# What is behaviour of opendkim while verifying an email with multiple dkim signatures?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dkim, opendkim

I am trying to implement DKIM verification using Opendkim and postfix. The doubt I am struck by is what will happen if the email has more than one DKIM signature and one of them fails (as like failed to validate/ integrity check failed). I know by default Opendkim processes the last three DKIM signatures but what if the failure occurred in say the first key it encountered; will it do the action specified in 'On-BadSignature' or skip this signature and move on to the second; and will only take the action if all the DKIM signatures failed. I am guessing former approach make much more logic but couldn't find any resource where I can confirm it.

Comment: OpenDKIM has not received much maintenance at all recently. Consider Scott Kittermans *dkimpy* implementation, or the DKIM module provided in *Rspamd* instead of setting up any new installation using the OpenDKIM software, which has a few known and possibly dangerous defects and is lacking important features.

Comment: @anx It'll be helpful if you can you please mention some of the defects in OpenDkim.